# Monthly Patch Releases for Linux CentOS/RedHat

Tags: centos, redhat, update, packages, patch-management

Can somebody tell me when **CentOS/RedHat** release **package updates monthly**? Micrososft has patch Tuesday but I can't seem to find a day/week when CentOS/RedHat release monthly patches. I'd like to schedule my environment patching around this if such a cycle exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a cycle does not exist (at least for CentOS). Updates are made available as and when they are ready. They normally lag Red Hat updates by a little time.

You can easily set up you own patch schedule and just update when it's time. Personally I monitor the CentOS Announce mailing list to see if there are any high priority updates that need to be applied outside of my general patching schedule.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4):

Red Hat does not withhold security updates for an artificial schedule, as some other operating system vendors do. They are [released](https://access.redhat.com/errata/) as soon as they are ready for deployment. That may be on any day of the year, including holidays.

Answer (score 0):

Most major patch update, since there is many libraries that need to account for the kernel. So basically, look for the kernel, which usually happens around the second or 3rd week of the month.  If you have a management system like Foreman/Katello, you will know when there is large sync.